# Update child bone matrices in Unity skinned mesh renderer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm manualy updating some bone transforms in a skinnedmeshrenderer in unity but the childs of these bones are wrong before the next frame and I need them for some operations.

As I'm modifying the world position I think I can calculate the updated child pose by using the parent transform and child local matrix but I don't know how.

Something like :

```
    foreach(var bone in myskmesh.bones)
    {
        bone.transform=bone.parent.transform*bone.localtransform;    //I know it doesn't exist
    }
```

EDIT:
Maybe that is a beginning:

```
    foreach(var bone in myskmesh.bones)
    {
        bone.position = bone.parent.TransformPoint(bone.localPosition);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void UpdateArmatureChilds(Transform startbone)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < startbone.childCount; i++)
    {
        var childbone= startbone.GetChild(i);
        childbone.position = startbone.TransformPoint(childbone.localPosition);
        childbone.rotation = startbone.rotation * childbone.localRotation;
        UpdateArmatureChilds(childbone);
    }
}
```